# Animating a chain in blender

Tags: animation, path

I simply want to animate a chain in blender, but cant figure it out. I have imported a 3d-model of a chain, that looks as following.
[image: Imported chain]

I have tried different approaches. I thought it was possible to animate it by making an circle/ellipse, and then set all of the objects to follow the path, but i can't make it work. Any ideas or solutions to this problem?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you managed to get this going?